# Слетает язык после завершения сессии

Tags: php

Работаю над локализацией сайта, столкнулся с такой проблемой, при смене языка в настройках сайта все работает, как нужно, но стоит только разлогиниться или вообще зайти на сайт без сессии, сайт не может найти языковой файл. В каждом шаблоне стоит такой код

```
<?php 
include_once ("lang/lang.".$getSettings['lang'].".php"); 
?>
```

$getSettings['lang']  это значение берется из базы, и имеет два языка Russian и English.  Собственно Логин ругается на отсутствие этой переменной. Подскажите, как обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Откуда у вас эта переменная берется на остальных страницах? От туда же добавляйте ее на странице логина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно в месте, где значение подхватывается из сессии, добавьте дефолтное значение. Пример:

```
$locale = $_SESSION['locale'] ?? '';
if(!in_array($locale, ['Russian', 'English'])) {
    $locale = 'Russian';
}
```

И уже после этого можете обращаться в базу данных или формировать `$getSettings`

Comment: Да, все супер, спасибо огромное! Единственное, что дефолтное значение придется ставить самому.. Благодарю Вас за помощь!